# Quarkus Resteasy JSON-B deserialize lists into HashMap instead of List<MyObject>

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to use Quarkus with Kotlin to create an API but I'm facing a problem related to the way that json-b is deserializing my json into my request classes.

Instead of deserialize into a List of MyRequestValue I'm getting a HashMap.

Not sure why json'b is able to deserialize objects properly but not be able to do the same with list of objects

Request Classes

```
data class MyRequest @JsonbCreator constructor(
    @JsonbProperty("name") val name: String,
    @JsonbProperty("values") val values: List<MyRequestValue>
)

data class MyRequestValue @JsonbCreator constructor(
    @JsonbProperty("id") val id: Int,
    @JsonbProperty("value") val value: String
)
```

Request Json

```
{
  "name": "Request",
  "values": [
    {
      "id": 1, 
      "value": "value1"
    }
  ]
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Instead of convert the json request into my data class objects, I'm getting MyRequest object with a hashmap as values instead of getting MyRequest object with a List.

Actual toString result: 
`MyRequest(name=Request, values=[{id=1, value=value1}])`

Expected toString Result: 
`MyRequest(name=Request, values=[MyRequestValue(id=1, name=value1)])`

Comment: Just to be sure, would the same thing work if the classes were Java classes?